# std::string stream parse a number in binary format

Tags: c++, c++11, binary, format, stringstream

I need to parse an `std::string` containing a number in binary format, such as:

```
0b01101101
```

I know that I can use the [std::hex](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/hex/) format specifier to parse numbers in the hexadecimal format.

```
std::string number = "0xff";
number.erase(0, 2);
std::stringstream sstream(number);
sstream << std::hex;
int n;
sstream >> n;
```

Is there something equivalent for the binary format?

Comment: You can use `std::bitset`'s string constructor.

Comment: There is no equivalent manipulator for binary.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`std::bitset` string constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/bitset) and convert bistet to number:

```
std::string number = "0b101";
//We need to start reading from index 2 to skip 0b
//Or we can erase that substring beforehand
int n = std::bitset<32>(number, 2).to_ulong();
//Be careful with potential overflow
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [`std::bitset`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/)

for example:

skip two first bytes `0b`

```
#include <bitset>
...
std::string s = "0b0111";
std::bitset<4>x(s,2); //pass string s to parsing, skip first two signs
std::cout << x;

char a = -20;    
std::bitset<8> x(a);
std::cout << x;

short b = -427;
std::bitset<16> y(c);
std::cout << y;
```

Comment: And parsing from string?

Comment: That's not what was requested in the OP. Read it again please.

Comment: you can parse `string` to `bitset`, after removing two first signs of `string`.